# Procedure executes fast when called from DBeaver but it takes ages when calling from C#

Tags: c#, postgresql

I have a very simple plpgsql procedure that executes in 1 second when being called from DBeaver but when I call from C# it's taking more than 1 hour. I have similar procedures that I call using the same method in C# and they run fine.

Have anyone suffered from this before?

My stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.datapipe_report_create_concatenated_columns_vida(in_report_id integer, in_client_id integer)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $procedure$
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO public.datapipe_report_staging
    SELECT DISTINCT
        report_id
    ,   row_number
    ,   506 + SUBSTRING(column_name, 10, 1)::INTEGER
    ,   'consumer_' || SUBSTRING(column_name, 10, 1) || '_phone_number'
    ,   COALESCE(
            MAX(CASE WHEN column_name ilike 'Customer % Mobile Number' THEN VALUE ELSE NULL END)
        ,   MAX(CASE WHEN column_name ilike 'Customer % Telephone Number Daytime' THEN VALUE ELSE NULL END)
        ,   MAX(CASE WHEN column_name ilike 'Customer % Telephone Number Evening' THEN VALUE ELSE NULL END)
    )
    FROM public.datapipe_report_staging drs
    WHERE report_id = in_report_id
    AND column_name ilike 'customer%number%'
    GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
    ORDER BY 1,2,3,4;

    DELETE FROM public.datapipe_report_staging
    WHERE report_id = in_report_id
    AND column_name ilike 'customer%name'
    OR column_name ilike 'customer%number%'
    OR column_name ilike 'security address%'
    OR column_name ilike 'Initial Rate Term'
    OR column_name ilike 'Remaining Term (months)'
    OR column_name ilike 'Interest Only Amount (Part and Part)';
END;
$procedure$
```

My c# call:

```
public static int ExecuteNonQueryStoredProcedure(NpgsqlConnection con, NpgsqlTransaction transaction, string storedProcedure, AddParams addParams = null, ProcessCommand processCommand = null)
{
    var sqlToCall = storedProcedure;
    try
    {
        using var cmd = BuildStoredProcedureCall(con, transaction, storedProcedure, addParams);
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
        var result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        processCommand?.Invoke(cmd);
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new DAOException($"Failed to call stored procedure: {sqlToCall}", ex);
    }
}
```

Explain of the first query inside the stored procedure:

```
Insert on datapipe_report_staging  (cost=14.82..14.83 rows=1 width=746)
  ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT*"  (cost=14.82..14.83 rows=1 width=746)
        ->  Unique  (cost=14.82..14.82 rows=1 width=76)
              ->  Sort  (cost=14.82..14.82 rows=1 width=76)
                    Sort Key: drs.row_number, ((506 + ("substring"((drs.column_name)::text, 10, 1))::integer)), ((('consumer_'::text || "substring"((drs.column_name)::text, 10, 1)) || '_phone_number'::text)), (COALESCE(max((CASE WHEN ((drs.column_name)::text ~~* 'Customer % Mobile Number'::text) THEN drs.value ELSE NULL::character varying END)::text), max((CASE WHEN ((drs.column_name)::text ~~* 'Customer % Telephone Number Daytime'::text) THEN drs.value ELSE NULL::character varying END)::text), max((CASE WHEN ((drs.column_name)::text ~~* 'Customer % Telephone Number Evening'::text) THEN drs.value ELSE NULL::character varying END)::text)))
                    ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=14.81..14.82 rows=1 width=76)
                          Group Key: drs.report_id, drs.row_number, ((506 + ("substring"((drs.column_name)::text, 10, 1))::integer)), ((('consumer_'::text || "substring"((drs.column_name)::text, 10, 1)) || '_phone_number'::text))
                          ->  Sort  (cost=14.81..14.81 rows=1 width=72)
                                Sort Key: drs.row_number, ((506 + ("substring"((drs.column_name)::text, 10, 1))::integer)), ((('consumer_'::text || "substring"((drs.column_name)::text, 10, 1)) || '_phone_number'::text))
                                ->  Seq Scan on datapipe_report_staging drs  (cost=0.00..14.80 rows=1 width=72)
                                      Filter: (((column_name)::text ~~* 'customer%number%'::text) AND (report_id = 1025))
```

Explain of the delete:

```
Delete on datapipe_report_staging  (cost=0.00..17.80 rows=1 width=6)
  ->  Seq Scan on datapipe_report_staging  (cost=0.00..17.80 rows=1 width=6)
        Filter: (((report_id = 1025) AND ((column_name)::text ~~* 'customer%name'::text)) OR ((column_name)::text ~~* 'customer%number%'::text) OR ((column_name)::text ~~* 'security address%'::text) OR ((column_name)::text ~~* 'Initial Rate Term'::text) OR ((column_name)::text ~~* 'Remaining Term (months)'::text) OR ((column_name)::text ~~* 'Interest Only Amount (Part and Part)'::text))
```

Comment: Is the `explain plan` the same? Please share both versions if different

Comment: A running transaction maybe ?

Comment: I've added the explains, I'm not a specialist in PG but it doesn't look that bad to me.

Comment: All procs are the same, just some differences in the columns used in `column_name `

Answer (score 0):

After some deep investigation, I noticed that every time this proc was called an auto vacuum would initiate so it was basically waiting for it to be complete before actually executing the code.

:facepalm: